# Renaming a macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the same macro twice on a sheet. The sheet will not let me use both unless I rename one. Whenever I have tried it stops functioning.

Below you will find the two programs I would like to use. Can anyone tell me how I can rename the first so that it continues to work?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
'when entering data in a cell in Col A
On Error GoTo enditall
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Cells.Column = 1 Then
    n = Target.Row
    If Me.Range("A" & n).Value <> "" Then
        Me.Range("B" & n).Value = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
    End If
End If
enditall:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
'when entering data in a cell in Col C
On Error GoTo enditall
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Cells.Column = 3 Then
    n = Target.Row
    If Me.Range("C" & n).Value <> "" Then
        Me.Range("D" & n).Value = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
    End If
End If
enditall:
Application.EnableEvents = True 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Worksheet_Change cannot be renamed. Instead put all the code in one.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

On Error GoTo enditall
Application.EnableEvents = False

'when entering data in a cell in Col A
If Target.Cells.Column = 1 Then
    n = Target.Row
    If Me.Range("A" & n).Value <> "" Then
        Me.Range("B" & n).Value = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
    End If
End If

'when entering data in a cell in Col C
If Target.Cells.Column = 3 Then
    n = Target.Row
    If Me.Range("C" & n).Value <> "" Then
        Me.Range("D" & n).Value = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
    End If
End If

enditall:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```